# MQL4: How to convert the value of iHigh() - iLow() to integer?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, mql4, mql, mt4

```
  double _high = iHigh(Symbol(), Period(), 0);
  double _low = iLow(Symbol(), Period(), 0);
  double result = _high - _low;
```

Excuse my limited English.

The type of result is a `double` number, and I want to convert the double number to an integer number, but the number of digits after the decimal point of the result corresponding to each symbol is uncertain.

I really don't know what to do other than doing it differently depending on the symbol.

Answer (score 0):

> **Q :** *"How to convert the value of `iHigh()` - `iLow()` to integer?
> <sub>... doing it differently depending on the symbol.</sub>"*

**A :**
Yes, we need to do it differently, depending on each the symbol.

Something like this may be a way to handle this :

```
...
int iSymbolSpecificDIGITs = SymbolInfoInteger( Symbol(), /* here, or
                                          OrderSymbol(),          if looping OrderBook */
                                               SYMBOL_DIGITS
                                               );
...
int iHiLoDIFF = (int)( MathPow( 10, iSymbolSpecificDIGITs ) * _high )
              - (int)( MathPow( 10, iSymbolSpecificDIGITs ) * _low  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Main thing is to add NomalizeDouble to the result and add Digits in the bracket to sum everything up:

```
 Alert(NormalizeDouble(result,Digits));

Or 

Print("result:" + NormalizeDouble(result,Digits));
```

Comment: With all respect, an attempt to ***"add Digits"*** does not convert double into integer. If in doubts, given an instrument has _Digits == 5 and aPriceDomainVALUE == 1827.604 ... adding these is (a) still a double 1833.604 and (b) such a sum does not represent anything meaningful